# Using MATLAB dot notation to set multiple properties at once

Tags: matlab, plot

Recently MATLAB enabled handles to plots to use dot notation to set properties.

e.g.

```
set(plotLeft,'marker','o');
```

can now be

```
plotLeft(1).Marker = 'o';
```

Is it possible to use this new dot notation to set multiple fields at once. Some code below for an example:

```
clc; clear all;
x = logspace(-3,0,100)';
plot1 = sin(x);
plot2 = cos(x);
[hax,plotLeft,plotRight] = plotyy(x,[plot1 plot1],x,[plot2 plot2])
plotLeft(1).Marker = 'o';
plotLeft(2).Marker = 'x';
```

I would like to set this bit:

```
plotLeft(1).Marker = 'o';
plotLeft(2).Marker = 'x';
```

But in one line. I can access the marker types by:

```
plotLeft([1 2]).Marker
```

But it will not let me set them how I think it would work:

```
>> plotLeft([1 2]).Marker = ['o' 'x']
Insufficient number of outputs from function on right hand side of equal sign to
satisfy overloaded assignment.
```

[image: sample plot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`deal`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function to achieve this:

```
[plotLeft([1 2]).Marker] = deal('o', 'x');
```

`plotLeft([1 2]).Marker` creates a [comma-separated list](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) so you cannot assign to it directly, but you can use deal to handle it, it will be equivalent of this:

```
[plotLeft(1).Marker, plotLeft(2).Marker] = deal('o', 'x');
```

Comment: Thank you, never heard of the deal. I just wish there was a somewhat quicker way like I wrote, since this way sort of retracts from the usefulness of the dot notation, and goes back to how we 'set' things.

Comment: Since in this case `plotLeft` contains only two elements, you can also use the simpler `[plotLeft.Marker] = deal('o','x')`. No need for the `([1,2])` indexing.

Comment: Another syntax that might be useful if the same marker types are to be assigned several times is `m = {'o', 'x'}; [plotLeft.Marker] = m{:};`.